# How to make int expressions calculated in returned value from Integer.parseInt(str)

Tags: java, string, int

Java code...

If I have

```
int num = 10 + 5;
System.out.println(num);
```

The result is 15

And if I have

```
String str = "10";
int number = Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.println(number);
```

The result is 10

But if I have

```
String str = "10 + 5"; //here the problem.
int number = Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.println(number);
```

The result is error message.

How to do it correctly. What I want to implement is to take expression from a String and calculate it. I am forced to take it from a String because I take it from JTextfield, so I want to make the calculation for the returned String expression.

Comment: You need to parse the expression. See here for one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to do it directly because you need some sort of "expression evaluator". One way would be to use a javascript engine from the scripting library:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    String s = "10 + 5";
    int  result = ((Double) engine.eval(s)).intValue();
    System.out.println(result); // 15
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works very well. that was what I need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a similar question was already answered: [Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)

You could however write a pretty simple parser by splitting the string into an array and writing an algorithm to handle the operations.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write an expression parser to separate out operands and operators and then accordingly perform the operations. You cannot pass `10 + 5` to `Integer.parseInt()` and expect the evaluated result.